# Python/Flask mysql cursor: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'todoapp'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql = MySQL(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

There is error which is displayed after executing program:

cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'.

According to documentaction it should work. I use Ubuntu 16.04, I have installed MySQL and it works properly. Could anyone explain why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in :

```
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
```

Looking at **flaskext.mysql** source , that feature is not yet implemented .

And since **flaskext.mysql** is using **pymysql**  , you can use **DictCursor** from **pymysql.cursors**

Example :

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL 
from flask import Flask 
from pymysql import cursors

app=Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=cursors.DictCursor)
mysql.init_app(app)
cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are constructing cursor based on flask_mysqldb , and Flask app won't be constructed itself up until the first route is hit, which means the Flask app will be constructed inside a Flask Function, and that is when your MySQL connection also can be constructed based on your app.config params, and then your cursor can be constructed based on MySQL connection:
Flask Construction  > MySQL Connection Construction > Cursor Construction.

So you have to use your cursor constructor inside a Flask Function:
Instead of:

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Put:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks for this - makes sense.
Also why it wouldn't work from terminal!

Answer (score 1):

I used the `connect()` method instead of get_db() and it works with `Python 3.5.5`. I had the same error when I used get_db

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'test_db'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)

# cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
print(cursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = 3308 #here your port
```

[image]

Comment: apparently by default the port is 3306, but you must put yours

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

It maybe that you need to init the app for MySQL context.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
mysql.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
mysql.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'todoapp'
mysql.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql.init_app(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: try with this? @Raken it might have to do with how the object is made using the extension